# found error in laravel 5.4,Property [categories] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I am trying to display the product listing on listing page of the product. Each product has category.My table structure

```
categories
id  name  description
1   Cat1  Category 1
2   Cat2  Category 2
```

This is the category table having `id name and description`

```
products
    id  name  description category_id
    1   pro1  product 1        1
    2   pro2  product 2        2
```

This is the product table having category_id.

```
Product Model
    public function categories() {        
            return $this->belongsTo("App\Category");
        }
```

This is the product model where the products are belongs to category

```
Category Model
         public function products() {
        return $this->hasMany("App\Product");
    }
```

This is the Category model where the Category has many product

Now in the product controller on listing function I want the list of product with category name

```
public function index()
    {
        $product = Product::with('categories')->get();
        print_r($product->categories);die;
        return view('product.index')->with("list",$product);
    }
```

I want my Output should be

```
products
        id  name  description category name
        1   pro1  product 1        cat1
        2   pro2  product 2        cat2
```

I found this error `"Property [categories] does not exist on this collection instance."`

Comment: `categories` is a method so... `$product->categories()`?

Comment: print_r($product->categories());die; I changed to this as method it gives me error Method categories does not exist.

Comment: to access category name, you should use $product->categories->name

Answer (score 2):

When you run:

```
$product = Product::with('categories')->get();
```

you are not getting single products but all products so it should be rather renamed to:

```
$products = Product::with('categories')->get();
```

Further, looking at your database structure, each product belongs to single category so in `Product` model you should rename

```
public function categories() 
{        
    return $this->belongsTo("App\Category");
}
```

to

```
public function category() 
{        
    return $this->belongsTo("App\Category");
}
```

If you do this change, you should then again change

```
$products = Product::with('categories')->get();
```

to

```
 $products = Product::with('category')->get();
```

Going back to your controller assuming all your products have set category, you can display it like this:

```
foreach ($products as $product) 
{
   echo $product->id.' '.$product->name.' '.$product->description.' '.$product->category->name;
}
```

You can obviously do the same later in Blade view like so:

```
@foreach ($list as $product) 
   {{ $product->id }} {{$product->name}} {{ $product->description }} {{ $product->category->name }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: @vaibhav - The trend is to avoid the changing Marcin's answer. Maybe you can add your own answer and comment on some of the upcoming Laravel changes.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed in `ProductController` which is my product controllers function

```
 public function index()
    {
        $products = Product::with('category')->get();        
        return view('product.index')->with("list",$products);
    }
```

Also changed in Product Model

```
public function category() {
        return $this->belongsTo("App\Category");
    }
```

After these changes I got my expected result.